# Quantum equivalent of Bertrand's theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The classic Bertrand's theorem states that "The only central potentials for which all bounded orbits are closed are $V(r) \propto 1/r$ and $V(r) \propto r^2$". I have a hard time to see what could be the quantum equivalent of this proposition but, at least, do these two potentials enjoy unique properties relative to the solutions of Schroedinger equation?

Comment: Can you define what *you* consider a "bound closed orbit" can be defined as in a quantum system ?  Note there is a paper [on Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9905011v1), although it may not match your idea of such a theorem.

Comment: [Greenberg 1966](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1972517) .

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They both have operators other than the angular momentum that commute with the Hamiltonian. These lead to additional degeneracies beyond the ones required by angular momentum i.e. rotational invariance. For the bound states of the 1/r problem, the Runge-Lenz vector is conserved and the corresponding quantum operator commutes with the Hamiltonian. For the 3-d harmonic oscillator there is a Runge-Lenz tensor.

Comment: Yes, good point indeed. But I was actually interested in the properties of the solutions of Schroedinger equations. As you said, even classically, those two cases enjoy additional symmetries, and this can actually be used to prove Bertrand's theorem, which is a statement about the solutions of Newton equations. I added that precision to my question.

Comment: The additional symmetries produce "accidental degeneracies" (now an obsolete misnomer) permittin algebraic solution of the problem, bypassing the Schroedinger equation altogether, and a better appreciation of their spectrum. Wybourne's classic group theory book details the somewhat larger class of Hamiltonians with these properties.